# Doubts about notifications in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi, I am creating a reader application, which Is used to share text on Facebook and twitter.

Every thing works perfectly. My client wants the login information for Facebook and Twitter in the settings page. The login and logout has to be done in there, too.
Only after logging in the user can share the text, there is a log in button and log out button for both Twitter and Facebook and the logout button is hidden behind the login button.

If the user clicks the login button and the login process is complete, the logout button unhides and the login button hides and vice versa.

Everything works fine for me, but the problem is when I redirect to next page and come to the settings page, the buttons' visibilities are reset to default:
If the user logs in, the logout button unhides. But when the user goes to any other page and comes back, the login button is visible again. This is because when opening another page and coming back, it's handled as a new case in the settings page. 
I think I can solve this by providing notifications or NSMutableDictionary. But i don't know how to do this. My code for login for Facebook and Twitter is:

logout for twitter

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtntwitterlogeout:(id)sender
{
    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = YES;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=NO;

    [_engine clearAccessToken];
    [_engine clearsCookies];
    [_engine setClearsCookies:YES];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"authData"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"authName"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authName"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authData"]);

    [_engine release];
    _engine=nil;   

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"twitter"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }

}
```

logein for twitter authentication

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnTwitter:(id)sender
{

    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = NO;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=YES;
    if (_engine) return;
    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
    _engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;

    UIViewController            *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];

    if (controller) 
        [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
    else {
        [_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. %@", [NSDate date]]];
    }
}
```

same as there for facebook.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "English" in your question is basically unreadable.

Comment: A bit of punctuation (i.e. captial letters and full stops) would really improve the introducing paragraphs.  They would also be better if they were shorter.

Comment: I tried to edit the text for him to actually make it readable (edit request is pending)

Comment: Wait a couple of minutes and it should be edited. I cannot edit posts directly yet because I need more reputation for it. So others have to review my edit and accept or decline it.

Comment: I understood it but I cannot help you unfortunately. Maybe now that it's easier to read, other people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a reference to the variable where you store the logged user data on the view that handles your login (and logout).

Are you using `UIViews` inside the `UINavigationController`, correct? That's what I'm assuming. If not, clarify, and I'll try to fix the answer accordingly.

Here's a simple workflow:

- User logins
- Once login is accepted, create (or update) a "userinfo" object (could be a dedicated class or a `NSMutableDictionary`)
- Make a reference to that object in your login view
- Create a new view (what you call the "next page"), reference this same "userinfo" object (where you should have stored OAuth keys, user name, id, and that kind of stuff) in this new view
- Push the new view

Once the user goes back to the first view, your view should check the "userinfo" object and act accordingly. Maybe using the `viewWillAppear:` delegate method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yea am using uiviews,the setting page is a subview of the main view,so there iss no issue within the mainview,but when i redirect to another viewcontroller and came back it remain in default posisitin that is changes were gone,but the login and logout functioanlity is ok there.but the hide and unhide of the button changed .

Comment: Once you create your "settings" view, you must tell it if the user is logged in or not. A simple property could do the trick. On the settings subview, on the `viewWillAppear:` method, you could check this property and hide/display buttons accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont You use NSUserDefaults to store the logins status .
Do it this way
If login succeeds

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"LOGGED_IN" forKey:@"FB_LOGIN_STATUS"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"LOGGED_IN" forKey:@"TWT_LOGIN_STATUS"];
```

else

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"LOGGED_OUT" forKey:@"FB_LOGIN_STATUS"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"LOGGED_OUT" forKey:@"TWT_LOGIN_STATUS"];
```

and on **viewWillAppear** method of your **view Controller** , check these objects to decide which button should be visible and which should be hidden . 
Hope it helps !!

Comment: so where did i put this code? in button click of login and logout of twitter and facebook right?and one more doubt in viewwill appear how to set the code ?i am newable to ios development,thats why .thanks.

Comment: To use the `NSUserDefaults` like Bharat J states, you should use the `viewWillAppear:` method to READ the values of NSUserDefaults (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to retrieve the logged information. And show/hide buttons accordingly.

Comment: @Sergio Moura yea thanks for the response,i am trying it ,but no luck

Comment: Try this: Once the user successfully logs in on twitter, call this method: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Twitter_logged"];`. On your `viewWillAppear:` method, do this: `BOOL logged = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Twitter_logged"];`, then `if (logged) { [self hideLoginButton]; [self showLogoutButton]; }` -- that should do the trick.

Comment: Oh! And after the user logs out, `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"Twitter_logged"];`